# How to create a trigger which fires when any insert or update is done in a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have created the below trigger, but it is not getting fired after i am doing new insert/update in to the mentioned table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ref_upd_user_phi_details
AFTER 
INSERT OR UPDATE --of emp_email_address, ssn_nb 
ON ref_adp_employees
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
      UPDATE ref_adp_employees
      SET emp_email_address = 'QA_' ||emp_email_address,
          ssn_nb = nvl2(ssn_nb, NULL, '123-45-6789')
      WHERE upper(emp_email_address) NOT LIKE 'QA_%'
      AND upper(emp_email_address) LIKE '%@KEENAN.COM';
exception
      WHEN others 
           THEN
               NULL;
END;
```

Can someone please suggest me what i am missing?

Comment: Why are you catching the WHEN OTHERS exception and doing nothing about it. Remove your exception section altogether for the time being and recompile the trigger. Do an insert /update and see if it is throwing any error.

Comment: Also, your update statement seems to be a static update. You are not using any values in the newly created or updated record in your trigger. What exactly are you trying to achieve by this trigger?

Comment: @phonetic_man: Let me check for the first condition you asked me to do, after removing the exception section. I want to fire this trigger when any new record is inserted or any existing record is updated.

Comment: Yes, I got that but the update query will execute for all rows in the ref_adp_employees table. Do you want that or you want the query to execute only for those rows which are being inserted or updated?

Comment: I want that for any insert or any update on ref_adp_employees will make change in complete table based on the provided condition. Also, can i create a procedure and call it within the trigger, and when insert/update operation happens this trigger will be fired and will execute the procedure within it?

Comment: Updating *every* row when any row is inserted/updated doesn't make much sense - why don't you just want to check/fix/modify the actual row being touched?

Answer (score 1):

As @phonetic_man pointed out, you are hiding any error you get by catching `when others` and taking no action. Without the exception block you would see that you are causing a mutating table error (ORA-04091), because you are referring to the same table the trigger is against.

If you took out the `for each row` part to turn it into a statement-level trigger then you would avoid that issue, but now you would have an infinite loop (ORA-00036) - when you try to update the table from within the trigger, that update itself causes the same trigger to fire again; which tries to update the same table yet again, which causes the trigger to fire yet again; etc. until Oracle notices and kills the process.

It would make more sense to use a before-insert row-level trigger to make sure the new values for the row match whatever pattern you are trying to enforce. Maybe something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ref_upd_user_phi_details
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE --of emp_email_address, ssn_nb 
ON ref_adp_employees
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF upper(:NEW.emp_email_address) NOT LIKE 'QA_%'
      AND upper(:NEW.emp_email_address) LIKE '%@KEENAN.COM'
    THEN
      :NEW.emp_email_address := 'QA_' || :NEW.emp_email_address;
      :NEW.ssn_nb := CASE WHEN :NEW.ssn_nb IS NULL THEN  '123-45-6789' END;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

And to see what it does:

```
insert into ref_adp_employees (emp_id, emp_email_address, ssn_nb) values (1, 'TEST_1', '123-45-6789');
insert into ref_adp_employees (emp_id, emp_email_address, ssn_nb) values (2, 'TEST_1@KEENAN.COM', '123-45-9876');
insert into ref_adp_employees (emp_id, emp_email_address, ssn_nb) values (3, 'QA_TEST_1', null);

select emp_id, emp_email_address, ssn_nb from ref_adp_employees;

    EMP_ID EMP_EMAIL_ADDRESS              SSN_NB    
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
         1 TEST_1                         123-45-6789
         2 QA_TEST_1@KEENAN.COM                      
         3 QA_TEST_1
```

Not sure if you really intended to replace set SSNs with null, and turn nulls into the fixed value; I suspect you are really trying to replace set values with the fixed string and leaves nulls alone, in which case it would be:

```
      :NEW.ssn_nb := CASE WHEN :NEW.ssn_nb IS NOT NULL THEN  '123-45-6789' END;
```

You might also want to move that outside the `IF` block, so it's done regardless of the email address; I've replicated what your original code was trying to do but that might not be right.

If you have existing data that you want to modify to match these changes, do a one-off update of the whole table - don't try to do that inside a trigger.

Comment: This is working fine now:    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ref_upd_user_phi_details
BEFORE 
INSERT OR UPDATE of emp_email_address, ssn_nb 
ON ref_adp_employees
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF upper(:NEW.emp_email_address) NOT LIKE 'QA_%'
      AND upper(:NEW.emp_email_address) LIKE '%@KEENAN.COM'
    THEN
      :NEW.emp_email_address := 'QA_' || :NEW.emp_email_address;
      :NEW.ssn_nb := CASE WHEN :NEW.ssn_nb IS NOT NULL THEN  '123-45-6789' END;
    END IF;
      :NEW.ssn_nb := CASE WHEN :NEW.ssn_nb IS NOT NULL THEN  '123-45-6789' END;
END;

Comment: @Oracle_UNIX_aspirant - that isn't really going to be helpful to anyone else, and it's hard to read code (or see its relevance) as a comment. You seem to have put the `ssn_nb` change in again so it applies to all updates/inserts; you don't need it inside the `IF` block as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Google?  There's a myriad of answers and examples out there for triggers, but some things I see at this time:

1)  Change trigger to BEFORE insert or update.  Use AFTER when making changes to another table, or to run some subsequent process on the table.

2)  Take out the comment to the individual fields being changed or added.  That was good AFAIK.

3)  In your body of the trigger use WHEN INSERTING and WHEN UPDATING.  Or if you are just updating the table, change DDL to BEFORE UPDATE only.

4)  In the update, reference with set :new.emp_email_address = 'QA_' || :old.emp_email_address ... and so on and so forth.  That's where that old as old and new as new becomes important.

Comment: I tried with:create or replace TRIGGER ref_upd_user_phi_details
BEFORE 
INSERT OR UPDATE --of emp_email_address, ssn_nb 
ON ref_adp_employees
REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
      UPDATE HR.ref_adp_employees
      SET :new.emp_email_address = 'QA_' ||:old.emp_email_address,
          :new.ssn_nb = nvl2(:old.ssn_nb, NULL, '123-45-6789')
      WHERE upper(:old.emp_email_address) NOT LIKE 'QA_%'
      AND upper(:old.emp_email_address) LIKE '%@KEENAN.COM';
--exception
--      WHEN others 
--           THEN
--               NULL;
END;

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the trigger is valid or not by firing the below query..

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME = trigger_name
AND    OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
AND    STATUS <> 'VALID'
```

The trigger is firing after update..
try before update

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ref_upd_user_phi_details
Before
INSERT OR UPDATE
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the query. Also, if you could suggest what i am missing in creating the above trigger.